# How to allocate more memory to my Virtual Machine running on Fedora to avoid Heap out of Memory Error

Tags: linux, performance, jenkins, fedora, create-react-app

I'm running Jenkins on a Fedora Virtual Machine and have an app created by [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) .

When I try to build for production on my local machine, after ~8 minutes, it does get compiled successfully (although with the message: 'the bundle size is significantly larger than recommended...'

However, when I run the same script during my Jenkins build process, I get the following error: `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`.

The build script is as follows: `npm run build-css && node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts-ts build && npm run copy-to-build`.

My question is, how can I allocate more memory for my Virtual Machine running on Fedora so the script can run successfully before throwing the `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution for me was to set `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` in the .env.production file as described [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2555).

A better solution (although more time consuming) is [code split](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/code-splitting/) the huge files ( >1MB)